# How do I use this JSON to bind to a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui

This JSON comes back from existing server and probably won't be changed - checks out as valid using JSONLint. Autobind does not work on this, and I can't get a grid to work with it:

```
[
{
    "SearchResult":{
        "assets":[
            {
                "agent":"6.1.0",
                "id":1,
                "model":"Gateway1",
                "modelId":2,
                "name":"Name",
                "serialNumber":"Serial01",
            },
            {
                "agent":"M2M",
                "id":2,
                "model":"Gateway1",
                "modelId":3,
                "name":"Name",
                "serialNumber":"Serial02"
            }
        ],
        "searchCriteria":{
            "paginationEnabled":false,
            "rowsPerPage":-1,
            "startRow":-1,
            "totalAvailableRows":-1,
            "alternateId":{
                "@xsi.nil":"true"
            },
            "modelNumber":{
                "@xsi.nil":"true"
            },
            "name":"*",
            "serialNumber":{
                "@xsi.nil":"true"
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify the array with data in the [DataSource's schema](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schema-object).

Have in mind that the DataSource works with flat arrays. To display the "assets" try the following:

```
schema: {
  data: function(rawData) { 
    return rawData[0].SearchResult.assets;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/opocib/3/edit

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer and JSBin - :)